# django fulltext search mysql

Tags: mysql, django

I have the default `User` model in django as per below:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `auth_user` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `is_staff` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
    `date_joined` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

I tried to add full text searching by `alter table 'auth_user' add fulltext(first_name), last_name, email)`, and I keep getting the error `Error Code: 1214. The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`. Is there a reason why this doesn't support full text searching? I'm thinking it may be because I extended the model and added my own table?

Comment: The django docs also advise not to alter the table type of the models, most likely for this reason. I assume django will pick appropriate types or uses some best choice on its own.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-do-i-add-database-specific-options-to-my-create-table-statements-such-as-specifying-myisam-as-the-table-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fulltext indices only work on MyISAM tables, and yours is InnoDB. [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: So no way for me to do full text searching? :(

Comment: @kalvish: Change your table type to MyISAM?

Comment: Problem is that there're many foreign key constraints. This will definitely impact my application which uses them heavily.

Comment: @kalvish: 3rd party fulltext search engine, here you come! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Django-Sphinx for full text search or look at their implementation. https://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx